# Does anyone know ways to logging console on git bash(MinGW environment)?

Tags: bash, mingw

I'm usually doing the logging in Linux environment using like Teraterm and logs the console. These days I often use git bash and do the development in Windows. I wonder if I could do the logging as I do in Linux environment and google it, though cannot find any webpage introducing it. Does anyone do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if the question is to know if you can connect to remote host through mingw, yes

```
ssh "user"@"remote_host"
```

where `"user"` is the user name and `"remote_host"` the host.